# Why is random string generator only printing one String from my array?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
            let cardOptions = [self.apple, self.cherry, self.star]
            print(cardOptions)
            
            let randomCard = cardOptions.randomElement()!
            print(randomCard)
        
            
            // Update cards on screen
            self.apple = randomCard
            self.cherry = randomCard
            self.star = randomCard
```

self.apple = "apple", self.cherry = "cherry", and self.star = "star". I put the print(randomCard) statement in my code so when I click my button I can set what it is spitting out to the console. But for some reason .randomElement() is only assigning "star" to the randomCard variable when it is supposed to be random.

Comment: After the first run through this code self.apple self.cherry and self.star are all the same object.

Comment: That makes so much sense, I can't believe I didn't think of that

Comment: make it a computed property or simply `self.apple = cardOptions.randomElement()!`

Comment: if you want to avoid repeating an element just shuffle the array and use `cardOptions[0]`, `cardOptions[1]` and `cardOptions[2]`